# Properties of Green's Equivalence $\mathcal L , \mathcal R, \mathcal D$ and $\mathcal H$ on a Semigroup

Tags: semigroups, greens-relations

> > If $ar \mathcal R a$ , then the map $x \mapsto xr$ is a bijection from $\mathcal H_a$ onto $\mathcal H_{ar}$.

I know that

If D is an arbitrary $\mathcal D - $ class in a Semigroup $S$ and if $a, b \in D$ are such that $a \mathcal R b$ , then by the definition of $\mathcal R$ there exist $s , s' \in S^1 $ such that

$$ as = b , \ \  \ \ bs' = a\ .$$

The right translation map $\rho_s : S \rightarrow S$ such that $(x)\rho_s = xs$ thus maps $a$ to $b$ and maps $\mathcal L_a$ into $\mathcal L_b$.

Similarly $\rho_{s'}$ maps $\mathcal L_b$ into $\mathcal L_a$, the composition  $\rho_s \rho_{s'}$ is the identity map on $\mathcal L_a$ and  $\rho_{s'} \rho_{s}$ is the identity map on $\mathcal L_b$

We deduce that $\rho_s|\mathcal L_a$ and $\rho_{s'}|\mathcal L_b$ are mutually inverse bijections from $\mathcal L_a$ onto $\mathcal L_b$ and $\mathcal L_b$ onto $\mathcal L_a$.

We can say even more about these maps; if $x \in \mathcal L_a$, then the element $ y = x\rho_s$ of $\mathcal L_b$ has the property that

$$ y = xs , \ \ \ \ x = ys'\ .$$

Thus $y \mathcal R x $, and so the map $\rho_s$ is $\mathcal R$ - class preserving. It maps each $\mathcal H -$ class in $\mathcal L_a$ in a one-one manner onto the corresponding $\mathcal H-$ class in $\mathcal L_b$

I want to prove the required result by using this theory. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: When you say you "want to prove the required result" -- where does it come from? why do you know it is true? Is this a sentence from a paper, and if so, which one?

Comment: I want to prove : If $ar \mathcal R a$ , then the map $x \mapsto xr$ is a bijection from $\mathcal H_a$ onto $\mathcal H_{ar}$.This is a statement in a " Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory" book by **JOHN . M Howie**

Comment: Sir ,i think this could be  proved by using that i have written above

Comment: How does Howie prove this? What part of his explanation is not clear?

Comment: I am copying what Howie has written

Comment: he has written that : we have seen that if $as \ \ \mathcal R \ \ a$ , then $ x \mapsto xs$ is a bijection from $\mathcal H_a$ onto $\mathcal H_{as}$

Comment: Also you can see it on page -50 of this book

Comment: What you wrote is the proof.

Comment: @ Benjamin : This is not a proof ,but i think this is helpful to prove